# How to permanently disable Outlook's annoying ad bar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, advertisements

I'm using the Outlook mail client which comes with my Microsoft 365 subscription, and I keep getting these annoying promotional messages from Microsoft:

[image]

Microsoft Support tells me this can't be turned off, but I'm skeptical of that claim. Frankly, I get the impression that those kids can't support their way out of a wet paper bag.

Surely there must be a way to find relief. A registry key change or something somewhere? Does anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried closing it (right hand X) a few times.  I do not see this in my Outlook 365 subscription.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. But then another one shows up the next day (different message, always from Microsoft). I need to disable it permanently. Odd that you're not seeing it. I'm envious!

Comment: You cannot permanently disable this things. But turning off whenever you see it reduces it. I have not seen for a very long time.

Comment: That's maddening  But I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yes, you can only reduce the number of occurrences by manually turning this off.

Comment: [This](https://www.admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_DisableOutlookMobileHyperlink) group policy should disable the banner.

Comment: @Ramhound — That looks like it's the one! (And I absolutely *love* GPO ) I found the companion MSKB, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/installation/how-to-remove-get-and-set-up-outlook-mobile-app-on-my-phone-option). Care to make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft *Outlook* mail client is one of [many](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-office-outlook/?license=free&platform=windows), such as Mozilla's free [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) mail client. If the issue of annoying, objectionable, and downright pestiferous ads are a nuisance, try an alternative client.

There are advantages to using an alternative.

- Many clients are cross-platform. For example, there are versions of Thunderbird for Windows, Mac and Linux.
- The clients display mail from a number of sources, such as GMail, Hotmail, and Mail.com, in one consistent interface.
- Most third-party clients do *not* show advertising.
- Most third-party clients do *not* collect your personal information to sell to advertisers, [unlike Outlook](https://proton.me/blog/outlook-is-microsofts-new-data-collection-service). Use due diligence before installing software, though.
- Updates and changes to the client are at the user's discretion. Therefore, software developers realize that if an obnoxious feature is introduced, users will leave that application.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. As you've noted, there's plenty to dislike about Outlook, and I agree, but I'm not quite ready to jump the fence just yet. The deep Exchange integration has got me pretty well hooked.

Comment: "pestiferous " Love that word! 

Comment: @InteXX, try both Outlook *and* an alternative -- you do not have to uninstall Outlook. If you use IMAP, https://support.mail.com/pop-imap/imap/outlook.html, messages stay on the server, and can be viewed by *both* clients, even simultaneously.

Comment: Unfortunately, Outlook doesn't handle IMAP very well. The sync always gets screwed up, especially with drafts. FYI. Now, that doesn't mean that I couldn't Thunderbird in to my Exchange endpoint on IMAP, but since I already know in advance that I won't be switching it seems like it'd be an investment with no return. That said, I appreciate the sentiment. I truly do.